# Notepad++ Advanced Search and Replace

Tags: notepad++

Apologies if this has already been answered, but my searches have drawn a blank. I have a task to sanitise a number of device configurations by replacing the first 2 octets of an IP address. Trouble is these files contain a huge amount of IP's for different networks, so a simple find and replace is a nightmare. Does anyone know if it's possible to search out an IP address and then replace only the first 2 octets, examples below.

```
172.16.12.11 to xxx.yyy.12.11
192.168.12.11 to xxx.yyy.12.11
10.10.10.10 to xxx.yyy.10.10
```

Comment: Are there only IP addresses in the file? Are the IP addresses alone on each line? Could you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1831194/edit) and add sample text and expected result? And, also, what you have tried.

Comment: The text on the lines vary but the majority are 'set security address-book global address EXT::ZSEXT-INT-126 123.321.123.321/32'  Does that help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can test is in **Find what:** to enter:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})(.*)
```

and in **Replace with:**

```
xxx.yyy$2
```

This will search for from 1 to 3 digits, then dot, then again 1 to 3 digits, then the rest.

Do not forget to activate regex in **Search mode**

Comment: Thats brillaint - worked a treat - Thanks you so much